# Flask / Pytest error: AssertionError: The setup method 'before_request' can no longer be called

Tags: python, flask, pytest

first up, this is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434519/assertionerror-the-setup-method-route-can-no-longer-be-called-on-the-blueprin) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74195757/flask-pytest-userwarning-the-setup-method-route-can-no-longer-be-called-on-th) although it seems like it. The problem arises when I have more than one test function in my unit test suite. Full code examples below.

It is pretty trivial to see what is going on: The blueprint gets created once, but it is used twice by the two test functions, so `test_1()` first calls `before_request()`, then `register_blueprint()`. Then `test_2()` does the same thing again on the same object, which of course fails. How can this be avoided?

Probably by creating the blueprint(s) with a factory function. In this very dumbed-down example it'd be trivial, but in reality the app consists of many blueprints from several modules. I don't want to change them all only for the purposes of testing. There must be a simpler method.

The `record_once()` blueprint method [(Flask documentation)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint) seems to do exactly what I need, but it makes it worse by apparently registering the BP first and then calling the function (this fails even when only one `test_x()` function is run)

For the time being I'll cook up something that checks if the blueprint is already registered and skips the @before_request decorator, but that seems like too much of a hack for such a common setup.

Thanks!

**app.py**

```
import flask

blp = flask.Blueprint('admin', __name__)
@blp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    return('OK')

def add_blueprint(app):
    @blp.before_request
    def before_request():
        return
    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(blp)

def make_app():
    app = flask.Flask('dham_wsgi')
    add_blueprint(app)
    return app
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from .app import make_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = make_app()
    yield app

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    yield app.test_client()
```

**test_app**

```
def test_1(client):
    rv = client.open('a')

def test_2(client):
    rv = client.open('b')
```

**app.py with record_once()**

```
import flask

blp = flask.Blueprint('admin', __name__)
@blp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    return('OK')

def add_before_request(setup):
    @setup.blueprint.before_request
    def before_request():
        return

blp.record_once(add_before_request)

def add_blueprint(app):
    app.register_blueprint(blp)

def make_app():
    app = flask.Flask('dham_wsgi')
    add_blueprint(app)
    return app
```

Comment: Can you not move the `@blp.before_request` decorated function outside of your `add_blueprint` function so it is only run once alongside your `@blp.route` decorated function. Standard practice would be to register your blueprints within your application factory function but not to actually modify the blueprints themselves.

Comment: The blueprints are loaded from submodules in a standardized way. The purpose of adding the before_request decorator after import is to augment the blueprint with specific, additional functionality, and I wouldn't want to replicate that code in each blueprint module. But maybe I have it backwards, it's probably better to put that stuff into an extra module and import that into each BP, maybe I could get away with a one-liner in the BP. Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think of it before. Sounds like a better paradigm overall, although it probably doesn't make a difference in actual use.

Comment: If you are adding the same before_request function to all of your blueprints you could add it once directly to the app with `app.before_request(func)` within your application factory or you could use the `before_app_request` decorator to register it once on a single blueprint but have it called before every request on all blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

I bit the bullet and went with EAWs suggestion: I made a little module with a blueprint factory which is imported into every blueprint. Turns out it makes the whole code  cleaner and more readable, and it keeps all of the blueprint setup within its respective module. The thing I had before is an ugly solution that bordered on monkey patching.